# Unable to add Custom column in customer Grid

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm using magento 2.3.5 below is my code
**Custmergrid/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns">
        <column name="my_column" class="Shruti\Custmergrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Mycolumn">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">My column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**Custmergrid/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Mycolumn.php**

```
<?php
namespace Shruti\Custmergrid\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
 
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
 
class Mycolumn extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    protected $_customerRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;       
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }
 
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $customer  = $this->_customerRepository->getById($item["entity_id"]);
 
                $customer_id = $customer->getId();               
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = 'Here';
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell what issue you are facing. as i tried your code and it's working.

Comment: @AfreenSheikh Not showing in the grid

Comment: @AfreenSheikh what is your magento version?

Comment: 2.3.4-p2 magento I'm using

Comment: I tried in 2.3.5 also. it's working fine. it can be a cache issue. try by flushing cache once

Comment: @AfreenSheikh I resolved it, KiwiCommerce_CustomerPassword this third module is culprit for this issue